# Refreshing the view of UITableView

Tags: uitableview, refresh, tableview, cells

I understand the concepts of cell re-usability for Xcode 5.0 table views. However, I have one very weird observation which I don't understand and wish anyone of you could enlighten me here. Thanks.

I have implemented a table view with a search bar utility (just on top of the table view). Under each custom cell (prototype cell), whenever a user clicks on it, it will be marked with a checkmark (UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark). The number of cells are more than 10.

Observation:
- Without using any search, marking and unmarking a cell is working as intended. Cells are updated instantly along with their checkmarks.
- When doing a search, from the results given, marking and unmarking a cell is also working as intended.

[Problem] Here comes the weird issue: when cancelling a search, an already marked cell (marked during search) does not refresh itself in the tableview unless scrolling up or down is performed!

And hence, I wrote [tableview reload] at the end of tableview:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method. Obviously, it doesn't refresh the tableview for me. Without further changing any other code, merely modifying [tableview reload] to [self.tableview reload] under the same method works!

**Why is the only addition of "self." able to make the table cells refreshed instantly?** I have always thought the first argument, tableView, from the method (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath is as equal to self.tableview. Obviously, my interpretation in this case is wrong.

Thank you. I'm sorry for my lengthy post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that this `UISearchBar` comes from a `UISearchDisplayController`. Is that correct?

If true, that is a common misconception, but an easy one to understand.

When filtering your `UITableView` entries and showing results, `UISearchDisplayController` actually overlays the view with its own `tableView`, `UISearchResultsTableView`.

Thus, this overlaid tableView also gets to call data source and delegate methods on your implementation, and this is when the `tableView` argument from `tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` stops being equivalent to `self.tableView`.

This means that calling `[tableView reloadData]` during filtering actually asks `UISearchResultsTableView` to reload its contents, not `self.tableView`, a property of your `viewController`.

Comment: wow, yes uisearchbar comes from uisearchdisplaycontroller. Your explanation is clear and to the point! thanks.

Comment: I'm actually quite happy with your answer and really clear my doubts since from last night. Thank you once again.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Have fun developing!